# python3 for ubuntu can't find scapy?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, scapy

I'm trying to run a python script using scapy in Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded python3 with

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

and I'm running the file I have with

```
sudo python3 <my filename>.py
```

As for importing scapy into my python file, I've tried

```
from scapy.all import *
```

and

```
import scapy.all
```

and other variations I've found while browsing the internet. However, none of them work and I keep getting the "No module named 'scapy'" error.

My script worked when I ran it in python2 in the same environment using scapy, but I've made changes specific to python3 in another development environment and now need to run it in python3 in this environment.

Any ideas on how to get this working? I've tried updating python also, but I can't get it to upgrade versions.

Comment: Haha, I posted an answer about Scrapy. Woops. :D

Comment: You should be using virtualenv if you're not already.

Comment: The official Scapy project only works on Python 2.x; here's a Python 3 port: https://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: FTR the official Scapy now has full Python 3 support

Answer (score 3):

You have to install scapy library before using it. By what you write it seems you just installed python3 and not scapy. Either:

- install pip3 and then `pip3 install scapy` to install scapy library for all system
- (recommended) or use virtualenv and install the same way inside virtual environment, and then run your script inside the python virtual environment

On usage of virutalenv for python you can easily find many guides. Please, comment if you need assistance on that.